# How to Remove Something in a List in a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

There isn't much to this question but I can't find it anywhere else, so I'm asking it.

How do you search for something that is in a List inside a Dictionary in Python.

Here's an example:

```
mydict = {"aaron":["1","4","10\n","3","6"] , "paul":["7","4\n","6","15"]}
# Additional code here
print(mydict)

>>> {"aaron":["1","4","10","3","6"] , "paul":["7","4","6","15"]} #Notice the '\n' has disappeared...
```

I need to know what code would enable me to search through each part of the value's list on each key in the dictionary, removing any "\n" inside any part of the dictionary.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks :)
- Aaron

Answer (score 2):

Instead of searching for a '\n' in your list to remove it, just apply `strip` to all your lists.

```
In [1604]: mydict = {"aaron":["1","4","10\n","3","6"] , "paul":["7","4\n","6","15"]}

In [1605]: for i in mydict.keys():
   ......:     mydict[i] = map(str.strip, mydict[i])
   ......:     

In [1606]: mydict
Out[1606]: {'aaron': ['1', '4', '10', '3', '6'], 'paul': ['7', '4', '6', '15']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the dictionary, get the list, which is value, then loop through the values in the list and reset them without the newline character. Then reset the list for the key

```
mydict = {"aaron":["1","4","10\n","3","6"] , "paul":["7","4\n","6","15"]}
print mydict
for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
    for ind, item in enumerate(value):
         value[ind] = item.strip()
print mydict
{'aaron': ['1', '4', '10\n', '3', '6'], 'paul': ['7', '4\n', '6', '15']}
{'aaron': ['1', '4', '10', '3', '6'], 'paul': ['7', '4', '6', '15']}
```

Comment: Use enumerate instead of range

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> mydict = {"aaron":["1","4","10\n","3","6"] , "paul":["7","4\n","6","15"]}
>>> mydict = {k:[element.strip() for element in mydict.get(k)] for k in mydict}
>>> mydict
{'paul': ['7', '4', '6', '15'], 'aaron': ['1', '4', '10', '3', '6']}
```

Comment: That creates a new dict, it does not modify the original also k has to be in the dict so you don't need get

Comment: Thanks, this is the best and most efficient way answered yet :)

Comment: @Padraic, is it important here to modify the dictionary in-place rather than reassigning it? I'm not sure it makes much difference unless we're concerned about memory usage. And regarding `get()`, I like `get()`. I'm not sure it makes much difference unless we're concerned about the additional execution time for that method call (I assume `get()` is measurably slower than raw indexing).

Comment: The OP seems to want to learn how to modify a list in a dictionary, mydict[key] is more efficient and `{k:[element.strip() for element in v] for k,v in mydict.iteritems()}` will be more efficient again.

Comment: I couldn't tell whether modifying the original list was a Problem Y, so I guess that Problem X was to arrive at the desired resulting dictionary. I don't know the size/complexity of the dataset, so I think optimizations can wait until we know they're necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate through the dictionary, you can use:

```
for key,value in mydict.items():
    print (key,value)
```

In order to remove the '\n' from the strings, you can iterate and check if the string contains '\n', then remove this substring out:

```
for (key, value) in mydict.items():
    for item in value:
        item = item.replace('\n','')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: mydict = {"aaron":["1","4","10\n","3","6"] , "paul":["7","4\n","6","15"]}

In [2]: for k,L in mydict.items():
   ...:     for i,elem in enumerate(L):
   ...:         L[i] = elem.strip()
   ...:         

In [3]: mydict
Out[3]: {'aaron': ['1', '4', '10', '3', '6'], 'paul': ['7', '4', '6', '15']}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP's code suggests Python 3 and he did like another comprehension, so:

```
mydict = {k: list(map(str.strip, v)) for k, v in mydict.items()}
```

or

```
mydict = {k: list(map(str.strip, mydict[k])) for k in mydict}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [11]: mydict = {"aaron":["1","4","10\n","3","6"] , "paul":["7","4\n","6","15"]}

In [12]: dict(map(lambda (k,v): (k, [item.replace("\n","") for item in v]), mydict.iteritems()))
Out[12]: {'aaron': ['1', '4', '10', '3', '6'], 'paul': ['7', '4', '6', '15']}
```

Answer (score -1):

if there is only \n you can do it through this piece of code:

```
for i in mydict:
    mydict[i]=list(map(lambda s:str(int(s)),mydict[i]))
```

Comment: Instead of a `lambda` function that calls `int()` and `str()`, I think it would be better to take one of two options: 1. Use only string operations, with `map(str.strip, mydict[i])`. 2. Convert the elements to `int`s (they sure look like they should be `int`s to me) and leave them as such, with `map(int, mydict[i])`.